# How to fix 204 Network code (No content) on Restful API and ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, restful-url

I try to create very simple contact form with restful api on node.js and react, but when I try to send a message I receive Network code 200, and after I receive Network code 204 No content.

Is there a way to fix that, because my messages not coming in the email.

My Api.js file looks like that:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

const port = 4000;

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Welcome to my api');
})

app.post('/api/v1/', (req,res) => {
  const { body: { username, password }} = req;
  const params = req.params;
  console.log(params)
  var data = req.body;

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Gmail',
  port: 465,
  auth: {
    user: 'somemail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'somepassword'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: data.email,
  to: 'somemail@gmail.com',
  subject: 'New Request',
  html: `<p>${data.name}</p>
          <p>${data.email}</p>
          <p>${data.message}</p>`
};

smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions,
(error, response) => {
  if(error) {
    res.send(error)
  }else {
    res.send('Success')
  }
  smtpTransport.close();
});

})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('We are live on port 4000');
});
```

My App.js looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


class Contact extends Component {

    state = {
        name: '',
        message: '',
        email: '',
        username: '',
        password: '',
        sent: false,
        buttonText: 'Send Message'
    }

    formSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        this.setState({
            buttonText: '...sending'
        })

        let data = {
            name: this.state.name,
            email: this.state.email,
            message: this.state.message,
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        }

        axios.post("http://wwww.localhost:4000/api/v1/", data)
        .then( res => {
            this.setState({ sent: true }, this.resetForm())
        })
        .catch( () => {
          console.log('Message not sent')
        })
      }

      resetForm = () => {
        this.setState({
            name: '',
            message: '',
            email: '',
            buttonText: 'Message Sent'
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
          <form className="contact-form" onSubmit={ (e) => this.formSubmit(e)}>
          <label className="message" htmlFor="message-input">Your Message</label>
          <br/>
          <textarea onChange={e => this.setState({ message: e.target.value})} name="message" className="message-input" type="text" placeholder="Please write your message here" value={this.state.message} required/>
          <br/>
          <label className="message-name" htmlFor="message-name">Your Name</label>
          <br/>
          <input onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value})} name="name" className="message-name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" value={this.state.name}/>
          <br/>
          <label className="message-email" htmlFor="message-email">Your Email</label>
          <br/>
          <input onChange={(e) => this.setState({ email: e.target.value})} name="email" className="message-email" type="email" placeholder="your@email.com" required value={this.state.email} />

          <div className="button--container">
              <button type="submit" className="button button-primary">{ this.state.buttonText }</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Contact;
```

The weird thing is that two weeks ago I didn't get such a network error 204 and I only received network code 200 ОК and messages coming into my email.

[image: Screenshot from Network Console Log]

Can I take example how to fix this mistake ?